# Overflow: auto; not working Android 4.2 Browser

Tags: css

I have a sidebar which is sticked at the left of the page for responsive purpose this element has an `overflow:auto`, everything works perfectly, the problem is I have to support Native Android 4.2 browser which is not applying this property.

My app is made with Angular 2, I was trying to implement a directive or module but I got the same problem.

Does anybody know the best way to solve this?

This is my structure:

```
<nav  class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation__scroll">
        * Content goes here *
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: $light_blue;
  width: 275px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 71px;
  left: -275px;
  border-top: 10px solid $primary_blue;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all .5s ease;

  .navigation__scroll {
    height: calc(100% - 71px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not `overflow:auto;` that's not working in Android 4.2 Browser, but `calc(100% - 71px)`. Unfortunatelly, there's no proper workaround for it, other than specifying a hard-coded `max-height` or `height` before the `calc()` rule.

Example:

```
.navigation__scroll {
   height: 90%;
   height: calc(100% - 71px);
   overflow-y: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Best practice is to hard-code values to `height` based on popular mobiles sizes.

Comment: Wow, this trick solved my issue and made everything clean. Thank you so much.